Is there such thing as investment maximization? Is there a model?
I have been reading some information involving the current economic state of certain businesses, specifically those which are being invested in my venture capitalists. The discussion involves how they are trying to maximize the investments they receive rather than the profits they get. When I tried to look more into it, I feel like I got into a dead end because the stuff that came up involved wealth maximization and while the explanations for why it was being considered as wealth maximization makes sense in some ways it doesn't in many other specifically with it not really addressing any of the problems I have been hearing about investment maximization. To just give a brief overview, from what I have seen the problem with the firms who are investment maximizing lies in how they aren't really trying to ensure that their business is necessarily successful or that they are making good financial decisions in the short or long run. Rather their goal is to appear as if they are successful to outside investors, for example there might be data that they are getting which says a decision they want to make is a bad one, but if such a decision would attract investors firms/businesses will make that decision anyway in order to get that investment. While I understand investment as important for growth I wonder whether it can be shown with math to have bad consequences if one continues to run their firm/business in such a way.
